# Assebmly generated using VS Express and by VS other version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any difference between .exe or .dll files created by VS Express and VS Ultimate? Is any metadata inside assembly or something that tells which VS veraion I have used?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Visual Studio doesn't actually compile (produce) exe or dll files.  It uses the Command line compiler (`CsC.exe`) under the hood.  So it doesn't matter what version of Visual Studio you use to trigger the compiler.